# Avro after upgrading to JDK 17

Tags: java, gwt, avro

Working on upgrading an application from JDK 11 to JDK 17 and it has an issue with Avro that I'm not certain how to get around.   I did have a lot of messages about the new LocalDate(string) method was being deprecated and removed and I was able to take care of that in the regular code.   Howver in the Avro avdl file I have
@java-class("java.time.LocalDate") string orderDate
which is leading to
this.orderDate = new java.time.LocalDate(in.readString()).

I fixed this in code with parse(string) but not sure how to make the avro build that way or if I need to just make this its own class instead of using Avro.